# SVG not filling completely

Tags: css, animation, svg

I am trying to make an animation with SVG text that initially shows only the outer stroke of each letter and then the interior is filled with the same color. However, when the animation is finished, there are spaces that have not been filled. Is there any property that can be applied to the svg or any of the paths that allow me to completely fill the inside of each letter without needing to increase the thickness of the strokes? (So that the initial appearance of the animation is not affected) Example attached below:

```html
<svg id="testSVG" width="312" height="219" viewBox="0 0 312 219" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <mask id="path-1-outside-1" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0.632004" y="0.312012" width="311" height="219" fill="black">
    <rect fill="white" x="0.632004" y="0.312012" width="311" height="219"/>
    <path d="M13.152 52H6.896V3.31201H13.152V24.188H37.496V3.31201H43.752V52H37.496V30.036H13.152V52Z"/>
    <path d="M71.1932 10.996L63.2372 32.96H79.4212L71.4652 10.996H71.1932ZM56.3692 52H49.4332L67.7932 3.31201H74.8652L93.2252 52H86.2892L81.5972 38.808H61.1292L56.3692 52Z"/>
    <path d="M105.191 32.28V52H98.9351V3.31201H115.527C119.743 3.31201 123.324 4.71734 126.271 7.52801C129.263 10.3387 130.759 13.7613 130.759 17.796C130.759 21.9213 129.263 25.3667 126.271 28.132C123.37 30.8973 119.788 32.28 115.527 32.28H105.191ZM105.191 9.29601V26.296H115.663C118.156 26.296 120.219 25.4573 121.851 23.78C123.528 22.1027 124.367 20.108 124.367 17.796C124.367 15.5293 123.528 13.5573 121.851 11.88C120.219 10.1573 118.156 9.29601 115.663 9.29601H105.191Z"/>
    <path d="M143.574 32.28V52H137.318V3.31201H153.91C158.126 3.31201 161.707 4.71734 164.654 7.52801C167.646 10.3387 169.142 13.7613 169.142 17.796C169.142 21.9213 167.646 25.3667 164.654 28.132C161.753 30.8973 158.171 32.28 153.91 32.28H143.574ZM143.574 9.29601V26.296H154.046C156.539 26.296 158.602 25.4573 160.234 23.78C161.911 22.1027 162.75 20.108 162.75 17.796C162.75 15.5293 161.911 13.5573 160.234 11.88C158.602 10.1573 156.539 9.29601 154.046 9.29601H143.574Z"/>
    <path d="M192.206 29.356V52H185.95V29.356L169.562 3.31201H176.906L188.942 23.1H189.214L200.978 3.31201H208.322L192.206 29.356Z"/>
    <path d="M6.896 134V85.312H24.508C28.3613 85.312 31.6707 86.5813 34.436 89.12C37.2013 91.6133 38.584 94.764 38.584 98.572C38.584 103.377 36.3853 106.755 31.988 108.704V108.976C34.4813 109.792 36.476 111.22 37.972 113.26C39.468 115.255 40.216 117.544 40.216 120.128C40.216 124.117 38.7653 127.427 35.864 130.056C33.0533 132.685 29.5853 134 25.46 134H6.896ZM13.152 91.296V106.188H24.508C26.7293 106.188 28.588 105.44 30.084 103.944C31.58 102.403 32.328 100.657 32.328 98.708C32.328 96.804 31.6027 95.0813 30.152 93.54C28.7013 92.044 26.9107 91.296 24.78 91.296H13.152ZM13.152 112.036V128.016H25.732C27.9987 128.016 29.9253 127.223 31.512 125.636C33.0533 124.049 33.824 122.168 33.824 119.992C33.824 117.861 33.0307 116.003 31.444 114.416C29.8573 112.829 27.8627 112.036 25.46 112.036H13.152Z"/>
    <path d="M53.527 134H47.271V85.312H53.527V134Z"/>
    <path d="M69.5973 91.296V108.432H79.6613C82.2 108.432 84.3533 107.616 86.1213 105.984C87.8893 104.307 88.7733 102.244 88.7733 99.796C88.7733 97.5293 87.9347 95.5573 86.2573 93.88C84.6253 92.1573 82.5627 91.296 80.0693 91.296H69.5973ZM69.5973 134H63.3413V85.312H79.9333C84.1493 85.312 87.7307 86.7173 90.6773 89.528C93.6693 92.2933 95.1653 95.716 95.1653 99.796C95.1653 103.151 94.0546 106.143 91.8333 108.772C89.6573 111.356 86.892 113.011 83.5373 113.736L83.4013 113.94L97.0693 133.728V134H89.6573L76.5333 114.28H69.5973V134Z"/>
    <path d="M119.246 91.296V134H112.99V91.296H99.3898V85.312H132.846V91.296H119.246Z"/>
    <path d="M145.632 134H139.376V85.312H145.632V106.188H169.976V85.312H176.232V134H169.976V112.036H145.632V134Z"/>
    <path d="M185.994 134V85.312H200.886C208.32 85.312 214.282 87.556 218.77 92.044C223.303 96.532 225.57 102.403 225.57 109.656C225.57 116.955 223.303 122.848 218.77 127.336C214.282 131.779 208.32 134 200.886 134H185.994ZM192.25 91.296V128.016H200.886C206.552 128.016 211.018 126.407 214.282 123.188C217.546 119.924 219.178 115.413 219.178 109.656C219.178 103.944 217.546 99.456 214.282 96.192C211.018 92.928 206.552 91.296 200.886 91.296H192.25Z"/>
    <path d="M248.631 92.996L240.675 114.96H256.859L248.903 92.996H248.631ZM233.807 134H226.871L245.231 85.312H252.303L270.663 134H263.727L259.035 120.808H238.567L233.807 134Z"/>
    <path d="M289.823 111.356V134H283.567V111.356L267.179 85.312H274.523L286.559 105.1H286.831L298.595 85.312H305.939L289.823 111.356Z"/>
    <path d="M23.488 173.296V216H17.232V173.296H3.632V167.312H37.088V173.296H23.488Z"/>
    <path d="M56.8494 174.996L48.8934 196.96H65.0774L57.1214 174.996H56.8494ZM42.0254 216H35.0894L53.4494 167.312H60.5214L78.8814 216H71.9454L67.2534 202.808H46.7854L42.0254 216Z"/>
    <path d="M96.7341 173.296V216H90.4781V173.296H76.8781V167.312H110.334V173.296H96.7341Z"/>
    <path d="M123.121 216H116.865V167.312H123.121V216Z"/>
    <path d="M150.615 174.996L142.659 196.96H158.843L150.887 174.996H150.615ZM135.791 216H128.855L147.215 167.312H154.287L172.647 216H165.711L161.019 202.808H140.551L135.791 216Z"/>
    <path d="M184.613 216H178.357V167.312H185.973L209.637 205.188H209.909L209.637 195.804V167.312H215.893V216H209.365L184.613 176.288H184.341L184.613 185.672V216Z"/>
    <path d="M243.385 174.996L235.429 196.96H251.613L243.657 174.996H243.385ZM228.561 216H221.625L239.985 167.312H247.057L265.417 216H258.481L253.789 202.808H233.321L228.561 216Z"/>
    </mask>
    <path d="M13.152 52H6.896V3.31201H13.152V24.188H37.496V3.31201H43.752V52H37.496V30.036H13.152V52Z" stroke="#D97E9F" stroke-width="6" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
    <path d="M71.1932 10.996L63.2372 32.96H79.4212L71.4652 10.996H71.1932ZM56.3692 52H49.4332L67.7932 3.31201H74.8652L93.2252 52H86.2892L81.5972 38.808H61.1292L56.3692 52Z" stroke="#D97E9F" stroke-width="6" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
    <path d="M105.191 32.28V52H98.9351V3.31201H115.527C119.743 3.31201 123.324 4.71734 126.271 7.52801C129.263 10.3387 130.759 13.7613 130.759 17.796C130.759 21.9213 129.263 25.3667 126.271 28.132C123.37 30.8973 119.788 32.28 115.527 32.28H105.191ZM105.191 9.29601V26.296H115.663C118.156 26.296 120.219 25.4573 121.851 23.78C123.528 22.1027 124.367 20.108 124.367 17.796C124.367 15.5293 123.528 13.5573 121.851 11.88C120.219 10.1573 118.156 9.29601 115.663 9.29601H105.191Z" stroke="#D97E9F" stroke-width="6" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
    <path d="M143.574 32.28V52H137.318V3.31201H153.91C158.126 3.31201 161.707 4.71734 164.654 7.52801C167.646 10.3387 169.142 13.7613 169.142 17.796C169.142 21.9213 167.646 25.3667 164.654 28.132C161.753 30.8973 158.171 32.28 153.91 32.28H143.574ZM143.574 9.29601V26.296H154.046C156.539 26.296 158.602 25.4573 160.234 23.78C161.911 22.1027 162.75 20.108 162.75 17.796C162.75 15.5293 161.911 13.5573 160.234 11.88C158.602 10.1573 156.539 9.29601 154.046 9.29601H143.574Z" stroke="#D97E9F" stroke-width="6" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
    <path d="M192.206 29.356V52H185.95V29.356L169.562 3.31201H176.906L188.942 23.1H189.214L200.978 3.31201H208.322L192.206 29.356Z" stroke="#D97E9F" stroke-width="6" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
</svg>
```

```css
#testSVG path:nth-child(2) {
    //H
    stroke-dasharray: 256.77;
    stroke-dashoffset: 256.7679443359375;
    animation: svgfill 1s ease forwards;
}

#testSVG path:nth-child(3) {
    //A
    stroke-dasharray: 236.68453979492188;
    stroke-dashoffset: 236.68453979492188;
    animation: svgfill 1s ease forwards;
}

#testSVG path:nth-child(4) {
    //P
    stroke-dasharray: 213.42007446289062;
    stroke-dashoffset: 213.42007446289062;
    animation: svgfill 1s ease forwards;
}

#testSVG path:nth-child(5) {
    //P
    stroke-dasharray: 213.42027282714844;
    stroke-dashoffset: 213.42027282714844;
    animation: svgfill 1s ease forwards;
}

#testSVG path:nth-child(6) {
    //Y
    stroke-dasharray: 174.08380126953125;
    stroke-dashoffset: 174.08380126953125;
    animation: svgfill 1s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes svgfill {
    to {
        fill: white;
    }
}
```

Comment: fill might work depending on how you've drawn the letters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different method that draws an unstroked white version of your shape on top of your shape and then erodes it away. Not as smooth as yours, but better.

```html
   <svg id="testSVG" width="312" height="219" viewBox="0 0 312 219" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
        <filter id="erode-animate">
          <feMorphology radius="0" operator="erode">
            <animate attributeName="radius" from="0" to="5" by="0.2" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>
          </feMorphology>
          
        </filter>
        </defs>
        
            <path d="M13.152 52H6.896V3.31201H13.152V24.188H37.496V3.31201H43.752V52H37.496V30.036H13.152V52Z" stroke="#D97E9F" stroke-width="2" fill="#D97E9F" />
    <path d="M71.1932 10.996L63.2372 32.96H79.4212L71.4652 10.996H71.1932ZM56.3692 52H49.4332L67.7932 3.31201H74.8652L93.2252 52H86.2892L81.5972 38.808H61.1292L56.3692 52Z" fill="#D97E9F" stroke="#D97E9F" stroke-width="2"/>
    <path d="M105.191 32.28V52H98.9351V3.31201H115.527C119.743 3.31201 123.324 4.71734 126.271 7.52801C129.263 10.3387 130.759 13.7613 130.759 17.796C130.759 21.9213 129.263 25.3667 126.271 28.132C123.37 30.8973 119.788 32.28 115.527 32.28H105.191ZM105.191 9.29601V26.296H115.663C118.156 26.296 120.219 25.4573 121.851 23.78C123.528 22.1027 124.367 20.108 124.367 17.796C124.367 15.5293 123.528 13.5573 121.851 11.88C120.219 10.1573 118.156 9.29601 115.663 9.29601H105.191Z"  fill="#D97E9F" stroke="#D97E9F" stroke-width="2"/>
    <path d="M143.574 32.28V52H137.318V3.31201H153.91C158.126 3.31201 161.707 4.71734 164.654 7.52801C167.646 10.3387 169.142 13.7613 169.142 17.796C169.142 21.9213 167.646 25.3667 164.654 28.132C161.753 30.8973 158.171 32.28 153.91 32.28H143.574ZM143.574 9.29601V26.296H154.046C156.539 26.296 158.602 25.4573 160.234 23.78C161.911 22.1027 162.75 20.108 162.75 17.796C162.75 15.5293 161.911 13.5573 160.234 11.88C158.602 10.1573 156.539 9.29601 154.046 9.29601H143.574Z"  fill="#D97E9F" stroke="#D97E9F" stroke-width="2"/>
    <path d="M192.206 29.356V52H185.95V29.356L169.562 3.31201H176.906L188.942 23.1H189.214L200.978 3.31201H208.322L192.206 29.356Z" fill="#D97E9F" stroke="#D97E9F" stroke-width="2"/>
        
    <g filter="url(#erode-animate)">
    <path d="M13.152 52H6.896V3.31201H13.152V24.188H37.496V3.31201H43.752V52H37.496V30.036H13.152V52Z" fill="white" />
    <path d="M71.1932 10.996L63.2372 32.96H79.4212L71.4652 10.996H71.1932ZM56.3692 52H49.4332L67.7932 3.31201H74.8652L93.2252 52H86.2892L81.5972 38.808H61.1292L56.3692 52Z" fill="white"/>
    <path d="M105.191 32.28V52H98.9351V3.31201H115.527C119.743 3.31201 123.324 4.71734 126.271 7.52801C129.263 10.3387 130.759 13.7613 130.759 17.796C130.759 21.9213 129.263 25.3667 126.271 28.132C123.37 30.8973 119.788 32.28 115.527 32.28H105.191ZM105.191 9.29601V26.296H115.663C118.156 26.296 120.219 25.4573 121.851 23.78C123.528 22.1027 124.367 20.108 124.367 17.796C124.367 15.5293 123.528 13.5573 121.851 11.88C120.219 10.1573 118.156 9.29601 115.663 9.29601H105.191Z"  fill="white"/>
    <path d="M143.574 32.28V52H137.318V3.31201H153.91C158.126 3.31201 161.707 4.71734 164.654 7.52801C167.646 10.3387 169.142 13.7613 169.142 17.796C169.142 21.9213 167.646 25.3667 164.654 28.132C161.753 30.8973 158.171 32.28 153.91 32.28H143.574ZM143.574 9.29601V26.296H154.046C156.539 26.296 158.602 25.4573 160.234 23.78C161.911 22.1027 162.75 20.108 162.75 17.796C162.75 15.5293 161.911 13.5573 160.234 11.88C158.602 10.1573 156.539 9.29601 154.046 9.29601H143.574Z"  fill="white"/>
    <path d="M192.206 29.356V52H185.95V29.356L169.562 3.31201H176.906L188.942 23.1H189.214L200.978 3.31201H208.322L192.206 29.356Z" fill="white"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to boil down (and comment) the code as much as possible, that makes reading and debugging easier. 
A few ideas that *could* work:

- duplicate paths with 0 stroke, then fill
- animate the filling with CSS directly
- create groups for each letter